# jQuery SlideDown, slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone can explain why 2nd click function doesn't work?

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
    $j('#quick-links-toggle').click(function(){
        $j('#quick-links-module').slideDown(300);
        $j(this).text('Hide links');
        $j(this).attr('id','quick-links-hide');
    });
    $j('#quick-links-hide').click(function(){
        $j('#quick-links-hide').slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of the way you're attaching the event handler. You're attaching the event handler on document ready, but you're dynamically changing the elements ID.

No element with ID `quick-links-hide` exists in the DOM when you're binding the event handler.

You'll need to delegate the event or, alternatively, handle this scenario in the same click event.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
    $j('#quick-links-toggle').on('click', function() {
        if($j('#quick-links-module').is(':visible')) {
            $j('#quick-links-module').slideUp(300);
            $j(this).text("Show links");
        } else {
            $j('#quick-links-module').slideDown(300);
            $j(this).text('Hide links');
        }
    });
});
```

In addition, the second handler is sliding the link not the link module. I don't believe this behavior was intended as the link module is what is being shown initially. I've corrected it in the code snippet above. Now the `quick-links-toggle` controls the visibility of the `quick-links-module`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use .on() instead on click() on element added dynamically :

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
    $j('#quick-links-toggle').click(function(){
        $j('#quick-links-module').slideDown(300);
        $j(this).text('Hide links');
        $j(this).attr('id','quick-links-hide');
    });
    $j(document).on('click', '#quick-links-hide', (function(){
        $j('#quick-links-hide').slideUp(300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    // some other code 
  });
});
```

It is more better way...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as simple as

```
$(function () {
  $('#quick-links-toggle').click(function () {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    $(this).text((txt=="Show Links")? "Hide Links" : "Show Links" );
    $('#quick-links-module').slideToggle(300);
  });
});
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju757/)

Answer (score 0):

Place the code inside a document ready method this way... Adios !

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('#quick-links-toggle').click(function(){
        if ($j(this).text != 'Hide links')
        {
             $j('#quick-links-module').slideDown(300);
             $j(this).text('Hide links');
        }
        else
        {
             $j('#quick-links-module').slideUp(300);
             $j(this).text('Show links');
        }
    });
});
```

Dynamically changing the id of an element will require the use of jQuery 'on' method.